# Can Hyacinth be grown in tropics?

Tags: hyacinth

I live in the tropics where It's warm almost all year round. Is it possible to grow Hyacinth?

Comment: we can't help you with shopping questions so I have edited that out.

Answer (score 1):

A good source of information is your country's system of botanic gardens or volunteer/charitable trusts set up to protect the country's native species. Also check out tourism organizations and golf courses where they do their best to stretch the envelope to accommodate people from temperate countries who are delighted to find their familiar plants in a foreign environment.

For example in India [tulips can be grown](https://www.agrifarming.in/tulip-cultivation/) and there is [a memorial garden which has a tulip collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indira_Gandhi_Memorial_Tulip_Garden). In such hot climates it is often necessary to take special precautions (such as a period of time in a fridge or even freezer) to give the necessary cold periods to achieve satisfactory blooming. So examine your country's topography carefully to see if there are regions where growing cool plants might be feasible.

Sources of plant materials really depend on the country's regulations regarding import of foreign living materials. Which country?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much you will be able to grow hyacinths in such a climate outdoors; hyacinths are native to the eastern mediterranean region, where there are cooler winters than yours, and are well suited to temperate climes. You don't say precisely what part of  the world you're in, but Hyacinths need 10 weeks at least of temperatures below 7deg c in order to put down roots and start the growing process. I suppose you could refrigerate them, potted up - this is what is known as 'forcing' bulbs and there's detail on how to do that in this link https://www.almanac.com/plant/growing-hyacinth-muscari#. Depending how hot your area is, the flowers may not last very long at all in higher temperatures. As for where to acquire bulbs, that rather depends where you are - many countries have restrictions on imported plant material.